# Unable to load a Jbutton to JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

I am trying to add a button to my form to bring the user back to the previous screen. I can display the form and drawn objects but unable to get the button to display.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
 public static JButton mainMenue = new JButton("Main Menue");

 public static void main(String[] args)
  {

//creating and setting the values for the Jframe   
JFrame form = new JFrame();

Color backColour = new Color(153,153,153);
form.getContentPane().setBackground(backColour);
form.add(mainMenue);
mainMenue.setVisible(true);
mainMenue.setLocation(100,100);
form.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
form.setBounds(30, 30, 1000, 1000);
form.getContentPane().add(new Layout());
form.setVisible(true);


}


@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{
//creating the seating 

    Font titleFont = new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 36);
    Font subTitleFont = new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 14);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawLine(225, 60, 255, 60);
    g.drawLine(340, 60, 400, 60);
    g.drawLine(400, 60, 400, 135);
    g.drawLine(400, 135, 650, 135);
    g.drawLine(650, 135, 650, 60);
    g.drawLine(650, 60, 680, 60);
    g.drawLine(765, 60, 825, 60);
    g.drawLine(225, 600, 450, 600);
    g.drawLine(600, 600, 850, 600);
```

Comment: Can you please update your code to include the part relevant to the button?

Comment: i don't have any code relevant to the button yet, i am currently just focusing on getting the button to display